# How to grant a TFS build agent access rights to TFS REST API?

Tags: rest, powershell, tfs, build-agent

I am following this question
[Are TFS Build Agent User Capabilities' Values Obtainable Within Build Steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850320/are-tfs-build-agent-user-capabilities-values-obtainable-within-build-steps) , specifically [Seva's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49539272/10580006), with direct REST API requests:

```
$tfsUrl = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
$token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
$authExpr = "whatever:$token"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($authExpr)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$headers = @{"Authorization" = "Basic $base64"}
$poolUrl = "${tfsUrl}_apis/distributedtask/pools/"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $poolUrl -Headers $headers
if ($response.count -eq 0)
{
  throw "No pools are accessible. No permissions?"
}
```

When run with my personal access token, this code returns an array of pools, in JSON. However, when run on a build agent as a build step using the agent-provided `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`, the `response.count` is zero and there are no pools returned.

Now, the answer linked above suggests that this is to be expected, and I need to grant permissions to the special user identity that the agent uses to communicate with TFS. Using the `${tfsUrl}_api/_common/GetUserProfile` REST endpoint (from the agent) I confirmed that this user is indeed named "Project Collection Build Service (*ProjectCollectionName*)", with *ProjectCollectionName* part being specific to a TFS instance.

So I go to configuration, Agent Queues, select my queue, Roles, Add, type until "Project Collection Build Service (*ProjectCollectionName*)" is visible, click it, check that Role is Reader, press Add. And the result is `Sorry, we couldn't add the Identity. Please try a different Identity.`. Same error if I go to Manage pools.

While I can use explicit authentication with username/password or a personal access token, I would really prefer to use the agent's authentication, because unlike stored credentials it's always supposed to work - you know, passwords change, tokens expire, likely at the least convenient moment.

So, is it possible?

Edit: this happens with TFS 2018 update 3

Comment: Do you have the `Allow agent access to OAuth token` option selected in your build definition? If not, `System.AccessToken` is blank. Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004090/vsts-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-in-release-managment

Comment: @Daniel I do. Otherwise, TFS returns a TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

Comment: Seva here :) Haven't tried on TFS 2018u3, only on u2.

Comment: You installed the build agent to run as a service?  On the build server, when you look at services, the account the agent is running as is "Project Collection Build Service (ProjectCollectionName)"?

Comment: @Matt Yes, the agent is running as a service, and no, it's running as a normal AD user account, not  "Project Collection Build Service (ProjectCollectionName)". Unfortunately, the agent does not seem to use this user account to communicate with TFS, and that's the problem. Otherwise I would just grant all the necessary permissions to this user.

Comment: I tried to authenticate with username and password, unsuccessfully. The only option that remains is the personal access token which is guaranteed to expire within a year.